# Python (2.7) send pdb output to file and automatic step

Tags: python-2.7, pdb

Win7 32bit

I have a long Python 2.7 script that crashes from time to time, likely because of a locked file or other inconsistent issue) and I'd like to log each instruction to a log file.

I am familiar with using pdb thus...

```
import pdb
```

then later...

```
pdb.set_trace()
```

While this works, it is cumbersome in that I need to manually start the debugger then single step the program.

Rather, I'd like to get the debugger to automatically do a next on all debug statements, and also have the debugger write the trace info to a log file.

That way I can run the script in the usual way (from an icon on the desktop.)

Then, when the script crashes, I can review the log file (I expect it will be rather long) and find the offending code.

Is there any method of doing this? Maybe a different debugger?

It should be noted I do have copious logging steps in my script that update a log. I have a procedure that opens a log for appending, writes a line at the end of the log, then closes the log. (I found if I left the log open, the last few log entries didn't get properly flushed if the program crashed.)

However, I'd like to see each and every script instruction.

Thanks, Mark.